# Ionic tab bar + Google Map , no events propagate into map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, google-maps, ionic-framework

I would like to build sort of a replica of the Google Maps app that has a tab bar on the bottom, a modal and the map.

However, if I have the tab bar + map taps into the map are not propagated to it. The map loads but remains dead.
When I remove the tab bar, events work fine.
I also tried moving the map up with `z-index` but that overlays the tab bar -> tab bar not visible.

Any idea how to get out of this?
I simply use the Goole Maps JS API to show the map, no third party component.

Here is the page

```
<ion-content>

  <div class="map-wrapper">
    <div id="map" #map></div>
  </div>

  <ion-modal id="mapModal" #mapModal
    [isOpen]="mapModalIsOpen"
    [initialBreakpoint]="0.1"
    [breakpoints]="[0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.9, 1]"
    [backdropBreakpoint]="1"
    (ionBreakpointDidChange)="handleBreakpointDidChange()"
  >
    <ng-template>
      <app-idle *ngIf="drawerIsIdle()"></app-idle>
      <app-settings *ngIf="drawerShowsSetttings()"></app-settings>
    </ng-template>
  </ion-modal>

  <ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">

      <ion-tab-button>
        <ion-icon name="map"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Map</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>

      <ion-tab-button>
        <ion-icon name="settings" (click)="settingsMenuTap()"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Settings</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
  </ion-tabs>
</ion-content>
```